# Does improper loading of a dynamic microphone cause damping or affect the coil movement?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, audio-engineering

Slightly struggling to find the right technical language to frame my question, but let me try...

- A dynamic microphone is effectively an electrical generator, similar to an alternator.
- I've read that adding a high electrical load to (drawing higher current from) an alternator creates a higher magnetic drag or counter torque on the rotor, which makes sense intuitively, since it's doing more work.
- So...does the same thing happen with the coil of a dynamic microphone if we treat at as a power source instead of a measurement device?
- Is this the reason that, instead of impedance-matching the pre-amplifer for maximum power transfer, we use impedance bridging (i.e. very high load/imput impedance in the ampl for drawing minimum current, relative to a low microphone impedance)? Would drawing too much current cause some kind of magnetic damping in the voice coil, thus preventing perfect sound capture?

Comment: EE stack exchange

Comment: @TigerGuy Thanks, posted it there.